# Facebook suggest a page to friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add a Facebook tab on my page that will allow users to suggest this page to their friends (this feature existed before but fb seem to have taken that down some time ago)

I know how to get the list of friends, but i am not so sure what mechanism should i use to send "suggestions" to their friends. Is Facebook [notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/notifications-api/) the way to go?

Or any other alternatives?